# Image request returns 403 on localhost

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-403

I'm developing a website, and when I run it out of localhost (as in file://path/to/website/index.html) it runs fine, but when I run through localhost/index.html (so I can test it with my PHP scripts) it returns 403 on image requests.

I don't think it's a folder permission issue, or else I wouldn't even be able to run it on regular path, right?

I'm using Apache and AngularJS, not sure if it makes any difference.

Comment: Where is the image location? How do you link to it? What does the `.htaccess` look like?

Comment: It's a permission issue. You can confirm this looking at your apache error logs. Debian/ubuntu that defaults to `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. And what do you mean by "run it on the regular path"? Is that command line or just you accessing the image via ssh? In either case, just because you can see the image doesn't mean apache can. You likely need to add read for the apache user, which isn't you.